# Airflow : Native operators vs containers

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using Airflow to orchestrate various batches and transformation processes. While writing a new process, I have come across a scenario where I need to transform BigQuery table into another table. I have two ways to implement this:

- By using [bigQuery_to_bigquery](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_bigquery.py) operator
- By writing my own container to perform the task and then use Docker or Kubernetes operator to invoke it

With the first approach, I will have my task eased and I won't need to maintain/bug fix anything. However, I will be combining Orchestration and Transformation together. With the second approach, orchestration will be separate from transformation but I will then have to maintain BigQuery APIs and connections.

Looks like both the approaches have their own advantages and disadvantages. Is there any recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

I will advise using native operators, especially for simple API calls like running a query in BigQuery. I use them in production and work great. You can pass query from files too.

I would advise using Docker or Kubernetes operators in case you need to run some heavy lifting transformation with custom code, which you could do on Airflow directly using the Python Operator.

Comment: Agreed. We use a mix of the kubernetes operator and native operators running on the kubernetes executor. Complete agree with @alessandro’s best practices. Use native operators for simple tasks and the kube operator for custom environment config sand complex tasks.